Need help with deriving a recursive formula for a control system optimization integral
I need some help with a problem that appears in one of the exercises of "Introduction to Stochastic Control Theory" by Karl J. Åström: Chapter 5, page 141, problem 8.
It is about deriving a recursive formula for computing the following integral:
$$\int_{-i \infty }^{i \infty } \frac{B(s)}{A(s) C(-s)} ds$$
Here, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are polynomials of orders $n$, $m$ and $k$ respectively and $m<n+k-2$. Also $A$ and $C$ have all their zeroes in the negative half plane.
A full derivation is given in the book (same chapter just before the exercise) for the related integral:
$$\int_{-i \infty }^{i \infty } \frac{B(s) B(-s)}{A(s) A(-s)} ds$$
The derivation involves contour integration which I am not very knowledgeable about, so I am not able to derive for this new form. I need the formula so that I can code and compute the results.
Is there a book or guide with solutions to exercises of this book (only ch 5 would suffice)? Or could someone help me in deriving the formula?
Any help is highly appreciated.
